# Android could not lock surface when puting shared preferences

Tags: java, android

Very strange thing. I found out that when I do `spEditor.putBoolean("closePxCmInfo", false).apply();` then an error occurs like that:

```
2022-01-03 10:47:39.761 3821-3917/? E/ViewRootImpl@6827b15[mierzenieopencv]: Surface is not valid.
2022-01-03 10:47:39.774 3821-3917/? E/ViewRootImpl@f395385[mierzenieopencv]: Surface is not valid.
2022-01-03 10:47:39.792 3821-3917/? E/ViewRootImpl@24f27f5[mierzenieopencv]: Surface is not valid.
2022-01-03 10:47:39.820 13383-13710/pl.jawegiel.mierzenieopencv E/OpenCV/StaticHelper: OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV
2022-01-03 10:47:39.824 3335-3449/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [Splash Screen pl.jawegiel.mierzenieopencv[13383]#0] connect: BufferQueue has been abandoned
2022-01-03 10:47:39.824 3821-3917/? E/ViewRootImpl@4fd5d5c[mierzenieopencv]: Could not lock surface
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
        at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:345)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:4018)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3979)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3721)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3029)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1888)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8511)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(Unknown Source:12)
```

It has nothing to do with my lauout I tested it out. The problem is with this line that I mentioned about putting shared preference.

Here is my code:

Stages.java

```
public class Stages extends BaseActivity {

private final Stage0StageFragment stageZeroFragment = new Stage0StageFragment();
private final Stage1StageFragment stageOneFragment = new Stage1StageFragment();
private final Stage2StageFragment stageTwoFragment = new Stage2StageFragment();
private final Stage3StageFragment stageThreeFragment = new Stage3StageFragment();

private BottomNavigationView bottomNavView;
private int startingPosition, newPosition;
OnSwitchFragmentFromStageTwo onSwitchFragmentFromStageTwo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Util.setThemeBasedOnPrefs(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.stages);

    spEditor.putBoolean("closePxCmInfo", false).apply();          // HERE IS THE PROBLEM

    bottomNavView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    bottomNavView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {

        if (bottomNavView.getSelectedItemId() == R.id.navigation_stage_zero) {
            if (!sp.getBoolean("correctionDone", false)) {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = Util.createAlertDialog(Stages.this, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info, R.string.hide_dialog_title, getString(R.string.stage_zero_confirmation), (dialog, which) -> {
                    spEditor.putBoolean("correctionDone", true).apply();
                    bottomNavView.setSelectedItemId(item.getItemId());
                    showFragment(item.getItemId());
                });
                alertDialog.setOnShowListener(arg0 -> setAlertDialogButtonsAttributes(alertDialog));
                alertDialog.show();
                return false;
            } else {
                showFragment(item.getItemId());
                return true;
            }
        } else if (bottomNavView.getSelectedItemId() == R.id.navigation_stage_two) {
            try {
                if (onSwitchFragmentFromStageTwo.onSwitchFragmentFromFragmentTwo() <= 0.5 && !sp.contains("closePxCmInfo")) {
                    AlertDialog ad = Util.createAlertDialog(Stages.this, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert, R.string.hide_dialog_title_alert, getResources().getString(R.string.benchmark_not_drawn), (dialog, which) -> {
                        spEditor.putBoolean("closePxCmInfo", true).apply();
                        bottomNavView.setSelectedItemId(item.getItemId());

                        showFragment(item.getItemId());
                    });
                    ad.setOnShowListener(arg0 -> setAlertDialogButtonsAttributes(ad));
                    ad.show();

                    return false;
                } else {
                    showFragment(item.getItemId());
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            showFragment(item.getItemId());
        }
        return true;
    });
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if (!sp.getBoolean("correctionDone", false))
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, stageZeroFragment);
    else {
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, stageOneFragment);
        bottomNavView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_stage_one);
    }
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
BaseActivity getActivity() {
    return this;
}

private void setAlertDialogButtonsAttributes(AlertDialog alertDialog2) {
    alertDialog2.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setBackground(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.button_selector));
    alertDialog2.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setBackground(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.button_selector));
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
    params.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
    alertDialog2.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setLayoutParams(params);
    alertDialog2.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setLayoutParams(params);
}

public void showFragment(int viewId) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (viewId) {
        case R.id.navigation_stage_zero:
            if (bottomNavView.getSelectedItemId() != R.id.navigation_stage_zero) {
                fragment = stageZeroFragment;
                newPosition = 0;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_stage_one:
            if (bottomNavView.getSelectedItemId() != R.id.navigation_stage_one) {
                fragment = stageOneFragment;
                newPosition = 1;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_stage_two:
            if (bottomNavView.getSelectedItemId() != R.id.navigation_stage_two) {
                fragment = stageTwoFragment;
                newPosition = 2;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_stage_three:
            if (bottomNavView.getSelectedItemId() != R.id.navigation_stage_three) {
                fragment = stageThreeFragment;
                newPosition = 3;
            }
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        if (startingPosition > newPosition) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right)
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        }
        if (startingPosition < newPosition) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left)
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        }

        startingPosition = newPosition;
    }
}
}
```

BaseActivity.java

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPreferences sp;
SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor;
BaseActivity childActivity;

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("CommitPrefEdits")
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(BaseActivity.this);
    spEditor = sp.edit();
    childActivity = getActivity();

    if(childActivity instanceof MainActivity)
        MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {});
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (childActivity instanceof Stages) {
        spEditor.putFloat("px_cm", 0f);
        spEditor.putFloat("rozmiar_px", 0f);
        spEditor.putFloat("rozmiar_px_x", (float) 0f);
        spEditor.putFloat("rozmiar_px_y", (float) 0f);
        spEditor.apply();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (childActivity instanceof Stages) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (childActivity instanceof Stages)
        return Util.onOptionsItemSelected(this, item);
    else
        return false;
}

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (childActivity instanceof Stages) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(childActivity, MainActivity.class);
//            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

abstract BaseActivity getActivity();
}
```

Help me please!